# launching python script in terminal at boot and keeping open if/when exception

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-3.8

writing a data logging program that is intended to run when raspberry boots.  I'm using lxsessions autostart to launch a shell script that has the command to launch my python program (my python script requires sudo)

while I continue to debug I would like the terminal window to stay open if/when it encounters an error.

I had done this successfully once before but lost my work.

my autostart file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@lxterminal -e sudo sh /home/pi/launcher.sh
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

my script file is:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Script is running

sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hms/hms5-1.py
```

I thought something like this (in the autstart file) would work, but no:

```
@lxterminal -e -hold sudo sh /home/pi/launcher.sh
```

a simple internet search spit out of examples on how to execute command at boot, even launching scripts but nothing has helped so far.  Thank you in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

So I rebuilt my Raspberry Pi and had to go through this again.  So after I was able to get it to work once, I followed my instructions from before, edited them to be clearer the posted here.  NOTE - I think the mistake I made before was using sudo (sudo nano) when I should have just used nano....

Also note the python program I am launching is `/home/pi/hms/hms2-v2.py`

*** setting this up is a 4 step process ***
YOU MUST HAVE XTERM

STEP 1 - INSTALL XTERM:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

STEP 2

read https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=227191

FIRST CREATE autostart here: /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
NOTE THE FOLDERS BELOW /home/pi/.config/ MAY NOT EXIST, IF NOT CREATE THEM EXACTLY AS ABOVE.  NOTE: the directory must be LXDE-pi NOT LXDE

Then edit the autostart file
by using nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

NOTE: DO NOT use sudo in the above command
put the following in the file:

```
#!/bin/bash



@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
sh /home/pi/launcher.sh
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

Step 3
create the script (.sh) file: launcher.sh in the directory /home/pi
include the following in the file launcher.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh


echo starting script
xterm -T "HMS" -geometry 100x70+10+35 -hold -e sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hms/hms2-v2.py
```

Step 4
make the .sh file executable with: `sudo chmod +x launcher.sh`